# Google Spreadsheet range notation -- non-continuous range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just try to write filter script.

I am now capable to use hideRows to do the filter functionality.

It will hide the rows according to the criteria one by one.

Want to improve it, and want to hide all of the filtered rows at once.

The rows will not in a continuous range, and in other words, it can be row:3~6, row:8 and so on.

So how to write a script to hide the non-continuous rows at once ?

Google script / Range seems not support non-continuous range notation...

```
Range("C1:C6,C9:C20") <<< Not work !!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all the rows that need to be hidden, and then hide them one by one. That's the easiest way.

With some extra logic, you could hide contiguous rows at the same time.